# iOS PayUMoney SDK-key is not valid

Tags: ios, objective-c, transactions, payumoney

I have integrate payumoney payment gateway. And I am able to create correct hash with the key, but at the end am getting an alert message as "key is not valid".what would be the problem?

Here is the code. I use the link "https://www.payumoney.com/payment-gateway-integration-guide.html" to download the payumoney SDK.

```
- (IBAction)startPaymentTapped:(id)sender {

    [self setPaymentParameters];

    //Start the payment flow
    PUMMainVController *paymentVC = [[PUMMainVController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *paymentNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:paymentVC];

    [self presentViewController:paymentNavController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}

- (void)setPaymentParameters {
    self.params = [PUMRequestParams sharedParams];
    self.params.environment = PUMEnvironmentProduction;
    self.params.amount = self.amount.text;
    self.params.key = @"mykeyvalue";
    self.params.merchantid = @"merchantid";
    self.params.txnid = [self  getRandomString:2];
    self.params.surl = @"https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php";
    self.params.furl = @"https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php";
    self.params.delegate = self;
    self.params.firstname = self.firstname.text;
    self.params.productinfo = self.productinfo.text;
    self.params.email = self.email.text;
    self.params.phone = @"";
    self.params.udf1 = @"";
    self.params.udf2 = @"";
    self.params.udf3 = @"";
    self.params.udf4 = @"";
    self.params.udf5 = @"";
    self.params.udf6 = @"";
    self.params.udf7 = @"";
    self.params.udf8 = @"";
    self.params.udf9 = @"";
    self.params.udf10 = @"";

    self.params.hashValue = [self getHash];

}

- (NSString *)getRandomString:(NSInteger)length {
    NSMutableString *returnString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];
    NSString *numbers = @"0123456789";

    // First number cannot be 0
    [returnString appendFormat:@"%C", [numbers characterAtIndex:(arc4random() % ([numbers length]-1))+1]];

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        [returnString appendFormat:@"%C", [numbers characterAtIndex:arc4random() % [numbers length]]];
    }
    return returnString;
}
- (NSString*)getHash {

    NSString *hashSequence = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mykeyvalue|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|||||||||||salt",self.params.txnid, self.params.amount, self.params.productinfo,self.params.firstname, self.params.email];

    NSString *rawHash = [[self createSHA512:hashSequence] description];
    NSString *hash = [[[rawHash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    return hash;
}
- (NSData *) createSHA512:(NSString *)source {

    const char *s = [source cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
    CC_SHA512(keyData.bytes, (CC_LONG)keyData.length, digest);

    NSData *output = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSLog(@"out --------- %@",output);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: what the key you passed in this two places `self.params.key = @"mykeyvalue";
    self.params.merchantid = @"merchantid";`

Comment: data which i got from the server team, for eg:
self.params.key@"mdyCKV";
self.params.merchantid=@"4914106";
[dummy values]

Comment: @Abhishek Biswas Have you solved this issue? Please reply asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check data when you send payumoney for create hash key with server api data for create your hash key.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.params.environment = PUMEnvironmentProduction;

Through the above code you can pay using net banking successfully. If you want to test 
your payment gateway for dummy credit/debit card some changes are required. I am 
listing it down. Try it.

Instead of 
self.params.environment = PUMEnvironmentProduction; //write   
self.params.environment = PUMEnvironmentTest;

change the urls as
self.params.surl = @"https://test.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php";
self.params.furl = @"https://test.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php";
// We need test url for testing purpose.

Make sure you have activated your payumoney account by clicking on link that you got in mail.
Use the below dummy master card details 

Test Card Name: any name
Test Card Number: 5123456789012346
Test CVV: 123
Test Expiry: May 2017
```